# Run Spring's .class instead of .jar file

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java Spring application which I built with `maven`, and a `.jar` file together with `.class` files were generated.

Instead of running the `.jar` file, is there a way for me to run the `.class` files instead?

I tried executing `java -cp . hello.Application` in the same directory as the `Application.class` (source code of `Application.java` below), but was given `Error: Could not find or load main class hello.Application`. Removing the `hello.` did not work either.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it's possible, but I'm not sure why you would want to do that. In any case, the classpath must also contain all the libraries used by your application (spring, etc.). Not just your the directory where your classes are.

Comment: @JBNizet It's complaining that it can't even find the main class for `Application` though (which shouldn't be the case if I'm in same directory with `-cp .`). I'm trying to test if this solves a problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966552/linux-delete-jar-file-after-running-it

Comment: If `.` is in the classpath, then you should run it from the directory containing the `hello` folder. This is basic Java stuff. You class is named hello.Application, so Java looks for it in the classpath (`.`), by matching packages with directories. so when loading `hello.Application`, it looks for `./hello/Application.class`. Deleting the jar file of your app while your app is running doesn't make any sense. That's like formatting your hard drive and hoping you can still keep using your computer. If you have less than 40MB available on your disk, then buy another disk.

Comment: @JBNizet it's an AWS server, upgrading it is not feasible atm. Running from directory containing `hello` works, thanks. Seem's like I'd need to get the `.class` files for all the dependencies (`SpringApplication`) for it to work though. Do you think running `.class` would allow me to delete the `.class` after application starts?

Comment: No. Again, no. Forget about that idea. And running .class will not help you save disk space. .jar files are zip files. They take **less** space than non-compressed .class files. Why are you trying to save a few MBs of disk space?

Answer (score -1):

I am doing the Spring boot application.I think you can also use maven to create a jar file and then use linux commend to run it.

Answer (score -2):

you can run a class by executing follow command :

```
java Application
```

for only simple console application. to run Spring Boot application you need maven to build jar file and executing jar file to call main method to load spring boot context. Spring Boot need several requirements and dependencies to run. Spring load context and create a special structure to load. for more you can see following links:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-exploded-structure/

Comment: I knew about the .jar. My question was how to run the `.class` instead. Your command gave the same error as what I mentioned in OP.

Comment: you can not run spring boot with .class file. .class file is only a specific java class. but jar contains all required java files to load application.